# Material UI Chips - stop them changing color when active

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

If you notice Chip number 3 below has a slightly darker background color because I have clicked on it and it is active. However there is no need for it to change color on being clicked/active, because only the delete button has a function, so the chip going darker on click/active has no meaning.

**How can I set the styling to stop this background color change when a user clicks the Chip?**

I think the custom styling has to come from react. In the devtools, I selected to make the element ':active', however it dosen't change color, so I dont think it is actually ':active' from a CSS perspective. The styling is all coming from React and the Material UI library, so I think we have to apply the custom styling within the React Component for it to work.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However there is no need for it to change color on being clicked/active, because only the delete button has a function

Please refer to the documentation:

"Note that since no onTouchTap property is defined, the Chip can be focused, but does not gain depth while clicked or touched."

http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/chip

The chip has focus color so that a user can tell when it is focused (whether through keyboard, mouse or touch). A focused chip receives the backspace keyboard input, so the user needs a visual cue as to which chip will be deleted.

Source: I wrote the Chip component.

Comment: Ok thank you. I get it now. Did not realise it could be deleted via keyboard when in focus, so the focus color does makes sense. Thank you!

By the way, the delete button that works is actually 'backspace', not the 'delete' button as I first tried